# What is the complexity of a `continue` statement?

Tags: c#, for-loop, time-complexity, complexity-theory, continue

I know this is something stupidly simple but it just occurred to me, while thinking about a bigger problem. Also, how would one verify it ?

```
List<int> items = new List(){10, 11, 32, 1, 101};

for(int x = 0; x < items.Length; x++)
{
   for(int y = 0; y < items.Length; y++)
   {
     continue;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's just a jump. It has the same complexity as `break` statement. Why exactly does this matter to you?

Comment: the continue statement has no inherent time complexity, it would only change complexity if used with a condition, in which case it's only reducing nesting

Comment: Within a `for` loop you might say `if(condition==true)` do something. Now "something" has an extra level of nesting. Instead you could do `if(!condition) continue;` which means whatever you do isn't nested inside the `if` statement. Either is fine. Neither is more complex. If we reduce levels of nesting it can make code a little bit easier to read, but even then it's a minor difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Continue` by itself has no impact on complexity as it has to be executed (in constant time) as part of loop iteration and corresponding loop will still have the same complexity whether it has `continue` or not (i.e. inner loop of your sample is still O(len_items) )

It may impact complexity if there is code that would conditionally executed in some cases and `continue` cut some iterations short:

```
for(int x = 0; x < items.Length; x++)
{
    if (x > 3 ) 
         continue; // outer continue
    for(int y = 0; y < items.Length; y++)
    {
       continue; // inner continue
    }
}
```

"outer continue" will impact (same as `goto` or inverse of the `if`) performance of whole operation - in this case O(n) as outer loop runs inner loop at most 3 times - O(n + 3*n) is the same as O(n).

"inner continue" has no impact on performance estimate as loop has to be running for every item anyway.

Similar reasoning applies to `break` - does not impact performance estimate unless it cuts the loop short at some consistent fraction of the loop (i.e. always stops after checking log N items out of N).

Comment: So if used with `if-else` could we make the outer loops run a constant number of times?

Comment: @heyNow `continue` just makes code easier to read (by intentionally saying "done with this iteration") it is no different than `if`/`goto`/`switch` otherwise... so not exactly sure what your comment is about. The sample I have shows that `continue` (under `if (x>3)` condition) will skip portion of the code after it, but exactly the same could be achieved by reversing condition and wrapping the rest of the code in it. Replacing `continue` with proper `if` may help in estimating performance depending on personal preferences.